# Locally installed Python vs system-wide installation

Tags: python, virtualenv, manjaro, python-poetry

I've got the following error with `$ poetry install`, while creating a virtual environment, probably.

```
ImportError

cannot import name 'enquote_executable' from 'distlib.scripts' 
(/home/alexey/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/distlib/scripts.py)

at /usr/lib/python3.9/site- 
packages/virtualenv/seed/embed/via_app_data/pip_install/base.py:10
...
```

The error is probably quite legitimate, as the distro Python is trying to import something from a Python located in `~/.local/lib` which I didn't even know was there :)

Can I learn something about how the local python got installed in the first place, and why an application from the distro repositories stumbles over it? It has not been always the case, by the way.

Comment: I would venture that there is not Python at that location. But usually it is the location where things installed with `python -m pip install --user` are placed. Which is OK. -- What is more surprising, is the location of virtualenv. -- How did you install poetry?

Comment: Both poetry and virtualenv are installed from the repositories. It used to work until some unnoticed event.

Comment: What repositories? And more importantly what commands did you use to install poetry and/or virtualenv?

Comment: Manjaro repositories. Very straightforward, something like `$ yay -S python-poetry`; `python-virtualenv` is actually a dependency.

Comment: Oh, wow... okay, then I have no idea. I don't know how they do packaging on that distribution, and if it is any good. -- Linux distributions tend to mess up everything that has to do with Python packaging tools. -- What I find strange is that some imports come from `~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages` and some come from `/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/`... -- Really, I don't know. -- My recommendation would be to uninstall the Manjaro versions of poetry, virtualenv, etc. and install directly with pip or pipx or something like that.

Comment: Thanks! So I let the matter rest... Bugs like this about poetry/virtualenv are common and ugly, it seems. Better not use it at all.

Comment: If Manjaro repositories have [`pipx`](https://pypi.org/project/pipx/), I would recommend giving it a try, then use pipx to install poetry and/or virtualenv (or any other Python tool actually). Otherwise you could give poetry's own auto-installer a try: https://python-poetry.org/docs/#osx-linux-bashonwindows-install-instructions

Comment: They do have pipx :)  Thanks again!

Comment: Uninstalled `python-poetry` from the reps, then `$ pipx install poetry`. It helped. For how long, there is no telling...